# Batch only use first letter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Basically I want some way to make a code that is like this
`set /p type=` then
`if %type% ==b`
`if %type% ==B`
`if %type% ==Ba`
`if %type% ==ba`
`if %type% ==ban`
`if %type% ==bana`
 ... up until
`if %type% ==banana`
`if %type% ==Banana`

or something like that. So is there a short cut or do I just need to say
`if %type% ==b` or `B`
or make them type the whole word out.

If there is a way to do something like they type `hhhhhhhhhh`,`help`,`h`,`hello`,`hi`, or anything that starts with an "h" it would act the same. That way I can do basically the same thing as up above.

Sorry, I wasn't really sure how to word this. Also it seems like the type of thing that might not exist.

Comment: you want to test if some variable starts with 'b'?

Comment: Yes but not 'b' specifically.

Comment: Exuse me, your question is not clear. Do you have several different words? Where they are loaded from? Do you want to list _all_ words that start with the same characters of the user input? If you just want _one_ word, how to differentiate it from the rest? Please, extend your question and include some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help.

```
@echo off

set $TestChar=h

set /p "$type=Enter your string : "

if /i "%$type:~0,1%"=="%$TestChar%" (echo First Char of %$type% is %$Testchar%
                                     exit /b)
echo First Char of %$type% is not %$Testchar%
pause > nul
```

Comment: This worked in the exact way you had it, but it wouldn't work when I tried to transfer it to the code I was working on. Also it should be; `( echo` not `(echo` but Ill assume it was a typo

Comment: I did get it to transfer correctly... Honestly I didn't think this would be possible.